# Pandas gives datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to compare two date values. My data contains a datecolumn.

```
    dateCols = ['Document Date']
    data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(delivery_file_path, f), parse_dates=dateCols,
                                   dayfirst=True, sheet_name='Refined',skiprows=1)

    data['Document Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Document Date'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Document Date'], data=data['Document Date'])
    print(df.dtypes)  <-- prints **datetime64[ns]**
    if (df['Document Date'] >= start) and (df['Document Date'] <= end):
.....
```

I get following error;

```
datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future pandas will
not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised. To retain the current
behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with
'pd.Timestamp'.
  if (df['Document Date'] >= start) and (df['Document Date'] <= end):
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is wrong with my above date comparison?

Comment: aren't u comparing a list with a single value. the error seems correct.. i think u just need to add .any() or .all()

Comment: @Eshaka No it is collision between 2 datetime objects?start and end parameters are python <class 'datetime.date'> objcets

Comment: that is not what i mean.. its trying to compare a list with one object. you can't compare the whole data list at once without specifying all or any. if u want to compare one by one you need to loop through the data list.

Comment: @Eshaka I tried like df['Document Date'].any() >= start. But getting TypeError: invalid_op() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skipna'

Comment: `if (df['Document Date'] >= start) and (df['Document Date'] <= end)`: 1) you should use `&` instead of `and`. 2) Even then `(df['Document Date'] >= start) & (df['Document Date'] <= end)` is still a series, and you can't do `if some_pd_series:` as @Eshaka suggested. Do `((df['Document Date'] >= start) & (df['Document Date'] <= end)).any()`. But really, post the next few lines of code. I guess you were trying to do something entirely different than evaluating the truth value of a series.

Comment: @Eshaka thanks adding .any() solved the issue. My problem is I added that for each start and end check.

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you point me what is the difference between & bitwise and 'and' logical operator?

Comment: `(df['Document Date'] >= start)` itself is a series, while `and` is the logic operator, only accepting `boolean`, i.e., `True` or `False` on each side. So when you do `if Series1 and Series2:` you still have the same problem of how to evaluate a series as `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out like adding .any()

```
if ((df['Document Date'] >= start) & (df['Document Date'] <= end)).any():
```

My requirement was, the file i process contain a monthly worth records or not. It is for data quality check. So using any() would be fine.

Comment: then i think you can count the number of records between that period. that will give u a better idea

Comment: Counting will give different numbers each time since new systems are added to process. So,before processing the file which i get from another 3 rd party process, i would like to make sure that file belongs to  a particular month and it contains record from 1st -31st/30th (end of month)

Comment: the condition you have just make sure you have at least one record in that month

Comment: are u supposed to have one record per day? or is it possible to have more than one? can there be day with now records?